# Zone with interacting objects

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, zone

I'm looking for the concept of a zone where I can display, move objects and interact with them.

But I don't even know how what it is called.

The better example I have is packet tracker:

[image: packet tracer example]

In my application, I can add some clients with their information and I want to programatically create a view where the user can see the interactions like that :

[image]

Can someone tell me how this kind of thing is called?

I'm using C# for Winform or WPF.

Thank you

Comment: You should look around for C# or WPF components (google it) and then check their demos. there are a lot of fancy components available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58914804/drag-and-drop-object-onto-canvas-with-coordinates

Comment: Maybe diagram designer. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1